# Fazendo Previsões usando LSTM com o Keras

Tags: python-3.x, redes, redes-neurais, keras, deep-learning

Bom dia, grupo.

Estou fazendo uns testes com modelos preditivos usando lstm com o `keras`.

No teste que eu fiz, eu treinei o modelo com alguns dados aleatórios que eu achei na internet.

Só que eu estou com dúvida na parte das previsões.

Para fazer as previsões no keras ele usa o `model.predict` com variavel `X` para fazer as previsões.

Tipo, eu treinei o meu modelo com 200 amostras por exemplo. Dai eu noto que ele faz a previsão para 200 amostras, uma vez que as entradas e saidas (X e y) possuem o mesmo shape.

Mas se eu quiser treinar o meu modelo com 200 amostras(no caso do meu modelo eu fiz o treino com 5 amostras) e fazer a previsão para 20 amostras (amostras essas que não fazem parte dos dados de treino e teste).

Resumindo, eu tenho dados temporais de 2012 até o ano 2018. Eu usei (não nesse exemplo) eu dividi meu dataset para treino de 2012 até 2017. Usei o ano de 2018 para testar o modelo (avaliar). Mas agora eu quero fazer as previsões (com o meu modelo treinado) desses dados para o ano de 2019. Como faz? Eu teria que criar um vetor vazio de tamanho "Z" (shape das previsões que eu quero) e usar ele no `model.predict`?

Abaixo segue o meu código.

Grato pela atenção.

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from numpy import array
from keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# return training data
def get_train():
    seq = [[0.0, 0.1], [0.1, 0.2], [0.2, 0.3], [0.3, 0.4], [0.4, 0.5]]
    seq = array(seq)
    X, y = seq[:,0], seq[:, 1]
    X = X.reshape((len(X), 1, 1))
    return X, y

# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(1,1)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
# compile model
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
# fit model
X,y = get_train()
model.fit(X, y, epochs=300)
# save model to single file
model.save('lstm_model.h5')

# load model from single file
model = load_model('lstm_model.h5')
# make predictions
previsao = model.predict(X, verbose=0)
print(previsao)

#Plotagem Previsões
plt.plot(y, color = 'red', label = 'Gravidade Real')
plt.plot(previsao, color = 'blue', label = 'Previsoes')
plt.title('Previsões')
plt.xlabel('Prev_Gravidade')
plt.ylabel('Gravidade Real')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se as suas amostras de 2019 estão no mesmo formato de entrada das que foram usadas para treino e para teste, você pode ou criar uma lista de arrays com todos ou fazer um `for` e ir jogando uma por uma na previsão e ir salvando os resultados.

A [documentação do Keras](https://keras.io/models/model/) diz o seguinte sobre a função de predição: 
`x: The input data, as a Numpy array (or list of Numpy arrays if the model has multiple inputs)`